# Переменная с данными из json вызывается раньше чем получает из него данные

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

я получаю данные из json таким образом:

```
$.get({
         url: "json",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(data) {
             param = data;
```

Сначала вывожу одну информацию в `success`, а потом записываю ее в `param`, что бы вывести другую информацию из этого файла позже.
У меня такая проблема param вызывается раньше, чем получает данные из файла, как сделать так, что бы сначала я получал данные из json и только потом выполнялось все остальное. Или может считывать json каким нибудь другим способом?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать async/await.
[Документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
[Неплохой пример с jQuery](https://petetasker.com/using-async-await-jquerys-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Если у кого то вдруг возникнет такая проблема, то вот как я решил, просто сделал запрос синхронным

```
$.ajax({
            url: "json",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false, // <--
            success: function(data) {
                param = data;

            }
        })
```